# Devise Custom Routes and Login Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, devise, partials

I'm trying to get Custom Routes working in my Rails application (Ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3).

This is my config/routes.rb file

```
match '/dashboard' => 'home#dashboard', :as => 'user_root'
devise_for :user do
   get "/login", :to => "devise/sessions#new" # Add a custom sign in route for user sign in
   get "/logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy" # Add a custom sing out route for user sign out
   get "/register", :to => "devise/registrations#new" # Add a Custom Route for Registrations
end
```

But submitting the form on /login or /register goes to users/sign_in
and users/sign_up. How do I prevent this from happening. Or even better make sure that by default all requests for users/sign_in etc go to the relevant routes and not the default routes generated by Devise.

Also how can I make the login form a partial to include it in any controller? So that I can have the Login Page on the homepage (home#index) and not on users/sign_in?

I'm using Devise 1.1.3 with Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9.2, on Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

With Devise 1.1.3 the following should work

```
devise_for :user, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :sign_up => "register" }
```

The routes it creates will not be appended with "/user/..." because of the `:path` parameter being an empty string. The `:pathnames` hash will take care of naming the routes as you like. Devise will use these routes internally so submitting to /login will work as you wish and not take you to /user/log_in

To add a login form to your front page there's info at the Devise Wiki:
http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Or do something like this:

```
 <%= form_tag new_user_session_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'user[password]' %>
 <%=  submit_tag 'Login' %>
```

Comment: In the code you put ":path", in the text you said ":as", fixed.

Comment: notice Devise 2.1.2 (later version) uses the plural `devise_for :users`

Comment: This approach works, but you are stuck using the default Devise path helpers like `new_user_session_path`.  To get helpers like `login_path`, you can put the `devise_for :user do` block that OP has right below this answer, and you'll get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me:

```
  devise_for :users do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Config:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'profile/edit'    => 'devise/registrations#edit',   :as => :edit_user_registration
    get 'profile/cancel'  => 'devise/registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
  end

  devise_for  :users,
              :path => '',
              :path_names => {  :sign_in =>       'login',
                                :sign_out =>      'logout',
                                :sign_up =>       '',
                                :registration =>  'register',
                                :edit =>          'edit',
                                :cancel =>        'cancel',
                                :confirmation =>  'verification'  }
```

Routes:

```
  edit_user_registration GET    /profile/edit(.:format)      devise/registrations#edit
cancel_user_registration GET    /profile/cancel(.:format)    devise/registrations#cancel
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                         GET    /register/cancel(.:format)   registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /register(.:format)          registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)          registrations#new
                         GET    /register/edit(.:format)     registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /register(.:format)          registrations#update
                         PUT    /register(.:format)          registrations#update
                         DELETE /register(.:format)          registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need don't put your special route in devise_for block

```
match '/dashboard' => 'home#dashboard', :as => 'user_root'
get "/login", :to => "devise/sessions#new" # Add a custom sign in route for user sign in
get "/logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy" # Add a custom sing out route for user sign out
get "/register", :to => "devise/registrations#new" # Add a Custom Route for Registrations
devise_for :user
```

Now /login works. /users/sign_in too.

Comment: I don't want the users/sign_in route to work. I only want the custom routes to work, and they should be active in all the controllers and views that use it.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own auth controller and routed devise sessions controller to my controller

```
devise_for :users, 
:controllers => {
    :sessions => 'auth' },

:path => '/',

:path_names => {
    :sign_in  => 'login',
    :sign_out => 'logout' }
```

This code will add /login and /logout urls.

More about this you can find in source code http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb

Comment: Canthiswait's solution works awesome, so I didn't try creating a new custom controller.

Comment: gr8 :)
of course you don't need controller setting :path_names is crucial

Answer (score 0):

Use this at the top of your routes.rb file

```
map.connect "users/:action", :controller => 'users', :action => /[a-z]+/i
```

use this on where your index file is. if it is on your users model, use the above or change accordingly

Comment: Will this work for having the login pages on the home page. They reside in the home#index. And devise (http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) uses the user model.

Comment: Doesn't work. My controller's name is home and it doesn't detect the route / on the home page.