# Devise routing error not understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this route file

```
 Qitch::Application.routes.draw do

     devise_for :users, :controllers => {
      :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks",
      :registrations => "users/registrations",
      :sessions => "users/sessions",
     :passwords => "users/passwords"
    }

   devise_for :users
    as :user do
    get '/sign_up', :to => "users/registrations#new"
    get "sign_out", :to => "users/sessions#destroy"
   end

  root :to => 'welcome#index'  
 end
```

when i click on this link in application layout

```
     <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign-up Now, It's fast and free</a>
```

i have this error

```
  Routing Error

  No route matches {:controller=>"users/welcome"}

  Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I don't understand why this occur

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) as the Routing Error promts, try to run *rake routes* which will show you all defined routes, from the output you can see if you defined something not as wanted

2.) as stated in [devise custom routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827011/devise-custom-routes-and-login-pages) try something like:

```
get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
```

3.) use the paths in your view: [generating paths and urls from code](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code)

```
<%= link_to "Login", signup_user_path %>
```