# Devise custom routing links not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am running Rails 3.2.12 and Devise 3.1 and I have in the routes.rb this:

```
devise_for :users do
  get '/login'    => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :login
  get '/logout'   => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
end
```

However, when I hit

```
127.0.0.1:3000/login
```

I get

```
No route matches [GET] "/login"
```

What works is

```
127.0.0.1:3000/users/login
```

Is there anything else I have to do so that I can skip typing /users/ part?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login'}
```

Good info about customizing Devise paths on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827011/devise-custom-routes-and-login-pages) :)

---

Here's some live code which works for one of our live apps:

```
  #User Management (Devise)
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :password => 'forgot', :confirmation => 'confirm', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout'}
  as :user do
    get 'register', :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
    delete 'logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

See [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) for more details