# Shared Devise links not routing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

In `/views/devise/shared/_links.erb` I have the following:

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

This links the "Sign in" link to `/users/login` at the signup page (at `/signup`).

How can I link it to just `/login`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827011/devise-custom-routes-and-login-pages this may help

Comment: this had been asked a thousand times already on Stack.

Comment: @zishe My question is a little different. I'm asking about the paths shown as the default links on the default devise views, not the route to the views themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `new_session_path(resource_name)` to `new_user_session_path` and it worked.