# Devise routes being awkward

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Devise is causing new_user_registration_path to link to registrations/new.user for no reason, I'm not sure why this is happening. I've barely customized Devise routes, and I'm not clear why this is happening. My config/routes.rb is below

gist.github.com/maclover7/e88cffe91587201da995

Comment: Can you post the rest of your `routes.rb` and the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/maclover7/e88cffe91587201da995

Comment: Just so you know, Registrations is a scaffold that is apart of my application's functionality, and has nothing to do with Devise

Comment: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/registrations/user" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="VUxMmTCygzDQ2gEPunSLGBWyb5GYa4uypb5iH5bpUSQ=" /></div>

Comment: I reset my Devise routes just to the regular devise_for :users, and I still got the error

Comment: @maclover7 edit your question, include your comments part there only.

Comment: Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827011/devise-custom-routes-and-login-pages

Comment: @lalit.sethi143 This solution doesn't work unfortunately, the signup form is still being POSTed to /registrations/user for seemingly no reason, and the signup link in the devise shared routes still points to /registrations/new.user