# Rspec test to post as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I am having problems trying to post as JSON to my controller action within my Rspec test:

```
RSpec.describe RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
  context 'Adding a Valid User' do
    it 'Returns Success Code and User object' do
     @params = { :user => {username: 'name', school: 'school'} }.to_json
     post :create, @params
    end
  end
end
```

At the moment I want to get a successful post request firing but am getting this error back all the time:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, @params
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/lnf".
```

My routes are setup like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 constraints(subdomain: 'api') do
   devise_for :users, path: 'lnf', controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

   devise_scope :user do
     post "/lnf" => 'registrations#create'
   end
 end
end
```

Rake routes outputs the following:

```
Prefix Verb              URI Pattern     Controller#Action
user_registration POST   /lnf(.:format)  registrations#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
lnf POST                 /lnf(.:format)  registrations#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

So I have two declarations for the same action?

Comment: Try to specify `subdomain`: `post :create, x: 1, y: 2, subdomain: :api`

Comment: getting the same error back..any other ideas?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use ```devise_for``` and ```devise_scope``` at the same time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827011/devise-custom-routes-and-login-pages https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes

Answer (score 0):

After a painstaking few hours, I have got my tests passing correctly and posting as JSON by doing the following:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
  before :each do
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
 context 'Adding a Valid User' do
  it 'Returns Success Code and User object' do
   json = { user: { username: "richlewis14", school: "Baden Powell", email: "richlewis14@gmail.com", password: "Password1", password_confirmation: "Password1"}}.to_json
  post :create, json
  expect(response.code).to eq('201')
 end
end
end
```

My routes are back to normal:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 constraints(subdomain: 'api') do
  devise_for :users, path: 'lnf', controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
 end
end
```

And in my test environment I had to add:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost' }
```

The key here was:

```
request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

Not fully sure as yet to what it does, it's next on my list to find out, but my tests are starting to run and pass.